# Two iOS TableViews in single View selection operation not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

In my iOS Swift application I am using two `tableview`s in a single storyboard. It's working fine but only problem is I am not able to perform selection operation in both tables.

It's scrolling and loading values without any issue, but `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not yet called.

Comment: you should provide your code. otherwise, you'll get lot of downvotes

Comment: show r tried code

Comment: Did you set delegate of both the tableviews?

Comment: check once are you connected the delegates from inspector to current class

Comment: Yes, I have Provided Code for both tableview and its is delegate and datasource.

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not Calling When We Clicking On TableView

Comment: Post your code here so that we can see.

Comment: This needed an [mcve], but since one was not provided, it should be put on hold.